# JS - EventListener click not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, addeventlistener

When the page loads it's supposed to show several small squares of different colors (and it does) and when I click the desired square, it changes the overall page background color to it. But the click doesn't work. For some reason the click goes through once when the page loads, so if I comment the last line in setbgcolor() out, the page becomes blue, otherwise it stays white like in presant code. Clicking after the page has loaded does nothing.

```
var colorArr = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Teal", "Blue", "Purple", "Grey"];

for(var i=0; i<colorArr.length; i++){

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.backgroundColor = colorArr[i];
    div.setAttribute('class', 'palette');
    div.addEventListener("click", setBgColor(div));

    document.getElementById('palette-div').appendChild(div);

}

function setBgColor(clickedDiv) {
        var bgColor = clickedDiv.style.backgroundColor;

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking setBgColor instead of passing it.

```
div.addEventListener("click", setBgColor(div));
```

To pass a method you need to leave the parenthesis out:

```
div.addEventListener("click", setBgColor);
```

You can then figure out which div was clicked, by investigating the `this` context in setBgColor.

Comment: Assignment states that I need to call setBgColor and that I should pass 'this' as the parameter so that the function knows which div was called. However I understand what you mean, it's like in Java, I should've though about it. So basiclly the assignment was wrong then?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't pass callback function this way. There are two ways to do this properly:

**Way 1:**

```
div.addEventListener("click", setBgColor);
```

Note that using this way you cannot define custom arguments for the called function. However, in this case, you don't need it.

`setBgColor` will be called with 1 argument - `MouseEvent` object which has some properties like `target`.

You can make your `setBgColor` function look like:

```
function setBgColor(ev)
{
    ev.target.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
}
```

This way is **preferable** because you add event listeners to multiple objects in a loop. As @Rodik mentioned in comments, the usage of anonymous functions within loops is definitely a bad practice.

**Way 2:**

If you only needed to assign a single function call, you could implement an anonymous function which would made the desirable function call:

```
div.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    setBgColor(div);
});
```

Comment: While this will work, defining anonymous functions inside loops is a bad pattern.

Comment: @Rodik Can you explain why?

Comment: @Rodik I agree. I didn't notice a loop. Of course, way 1 is better in this case. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Zim84 defining functions in loops can lead to scoping errors in some cases. it is best to avoid the practice even when such an error does not occur in the current example. for more info - https://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop

Answer (score 1):

```
ele.addEventListener("event", function(){//handler});//this syntax of addevent
 // but your code 

 div.addEventListener("click", setBgColor());
 // setBgColor ==>this function reference 
 // setBgColor()  ==> this function calling (in case of you its returning undefined )

div.addEventListener("click", setBgColor);//modify like this
```

check this

```js
var colorArr = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Teal", "Blue", "Purple", "Grey"];

for(var i=0; i<colorArr.length; i++){

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.backgroundColor = colorArr[i];
    div.setAttribute('class', 'palette');
    div.addEventListener("click", setBgColor);

    document.getElementById('palette-div').appendChild(div);

}

function setBgColor(event) {
        var bgColor = event.target.style.backgroundColor;

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
```

```css
.palette{
width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="palette-div"></div>
```